# How we show customer group name in magento 2 email template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

As of now, I created a customer from the backend, while creating a customer, it will send the welcome email template to that corresponding customer. In that, how I will add the customer group in the email template while creating a customer

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need. Dont forgot to initialize in construct.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $session;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $groupRepository;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomerGroupCode()
{
    $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($this->getCustomerGroupId());

    return $group->getCode();
}



/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getCustomerGroupId()
{
    return $this->session->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
}
```

Comment: How I will pass the variable into the template. I thought that it was not the correct answer. where I need to paste this code and how it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable with backend 'custom variables' and programmatically also

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection as CustomerGroup;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerGroup;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    CustomerGroup $customerGroup
)
{
    $this->customerGroup = $customerGroup;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCustomerGroups()
{
    $customerGroups = $this->customerGroup->toOptionArray();
    return $customerGroups;
}
```

}

```
$templateVars = [ 'customer_group' => $this->getCustomerGroups()];
```

And in send email funstion in set this variable like this

```
->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
```

and in your email template call variable `{{var customer_group}}`
i hope it'll work for you.